# Layered Navigation not affecting result on page

Tags: theme

I have created a module to show all products with special price.

I have added layered navigation to left block. It shows proper product count. But When I click any of filter (like category, price range), it doesn't affect number of products on page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you created your own collection to display products on a page? That indeed will not work directly with the layered navigation, since your custom collection will not be adjusted by it. Though that is all speculation for now. Perhaps you can share a bit more of your code to get a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have created my own collection to fetch products with special price. But I am not getting any way to modify collection after applying filters from left navigation.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Actually I was using my own custom layer where I was creating collection of products with special price. Now I changed the code, I am using default layer and in my block file I added code to fetch products with special price.

Answer (score 2):

As Tim said: Share some code and have a look into `\Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection` especially:

```
$layer = $this->getLayer();
// ...
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
```

The product collection comes from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` which handles the filtering.